# java concurrency happens before

Tags: java, multithreading

Say you have 2 threads with a shared array list of objects, then you go in one of the threads, and you alter the entire arraylist, by adding many more objects,

```
static ArrayList<Object> o =
static Object lock = new Object();
```

in Thread 1

```
         o.addAll(another arraylist);
         synchronized(lock){}
```

then say at regular intervals you have Thread 2 do something like this,

```
        synchronized(lock){}
        o.get(7);
```

the list will eventually get correctly updated but its accessing while getting altered in thread 1. Is this not allowed or something or will it run correctly?

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve? You know that `o` is not correctly synchronized, so this is not safe. What good is it to find out how "not safe" it is exactly?

Comment: the operation of adding all the objects to the arraylist is a long one, so treating it as volatile is faster. but your answer explains it if its unspecified then it should probably be locked. thanks

Comment: In that case (and if writing to it is rare compared to reading from it), then I might be able to interest you in a [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). It is "eventually consistent" and really fast for reads (and the reads are never blocked on writes).

Comment: Doing just this: synchronized(lock){} causes nothing really. It waits for the lock but does nothing, just after the lock is free, the line makes it immediatelly free, so I dont's see why to do that. the get/addAll is not in a mutex section

Comment: @SamAdams The problem is that the synchronized block in Thread 1 doesn't stop Thread 2 from trying to get the element **while** Thread 1 is doing the `addAll()`. And when that happens, all bets are off. You could even end up with a race condition that is impossible to get out of. http://mailinator.blogspot.com/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html

Comment: I think where you go wrong is that you assume that unless a memory barrier is encountered, threads will definitely not see shared state manipulated by another thread. But that is not true, only the reverse.

Comment: @biziclop but doesnt threading just get implemented in thread cache? as in lock, so flush cache and get shared? said this somewhere in oracle docs about volatile variables at least

Comment: @maslan the point was to create a happens before so that eventulaly it gets updated to new value and thread cache is flushed, but not sure if thats how it works

Comment: @SamAdams No, and don't even try to assume anything like that. Some threads may decide not to use the cache at all, then there's operation re-ordering, all perfectly valid things threads can do. The only guarantees are the ones around memory barriers like `synchronized` and `volatile` variables, but you have to be careful with the latter: `private volatile ArrayList list;` will not make modifications to the list itself atomic, only assignment to the `list` field.

Comment: ok thx thats what the problem is then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour is not specified. The `addAll()` could in theory be implemented in a way that would make the `o.get(7)` throw an exception, hang, return the wrong value or do any other thing.

With an `ArrayList` the hanging is a very unlikely option, but other structures (such as `HashMap`, `LinkedList`, ...) are less forgiving.

So basically you don't want to depend on "it won't be that bad, will it?"

There is one list implementation, which basically implements the "read the old content while changes are made" and it's the [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). If you just care about correct reads, but don't always need the latest one and if writes are far less common than reads, then this is probably a good solution.